# How to change background color of terminal cursor in Linux Mint 17.2 XFCE

Tags: linux, vim, colors, terminal

I have just started using *zsh*, *tmux* and *vim* together on a fresh install of Linux Mint 17.2 XFCE-edition. I am new on Stack Overflow.

My terminal cursor is a white box which keeps the normal color of letters in for instance vim. This means that it's impossible to see the white letters when marked by the cursor - white on white - and difficult to see fainter text colors like yellow. An example can be seen on the imgur-link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlNSb.png

I have tried to find a way to set the text under the cursor to black or some kind of invert, but without luck.

I hope you can help :)

Comment: First off, this question belongs in superuser.com, since it doesn't involve programming. However, from the image it looks like you running `vim` with a broken `colorscheme`, try using a different one? For example `colorscheme murphy`.

Comment: Yep sorry about wrong community.
The colorscheme seems to work fine (base-16-shell https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell). The same problem happens with *murphy*

I should also be more clear: the problem also arises outside of vim as in: http://i.imgur.com/blPZCuU.png

Comment: Then you might wish to take a look at your terminal color palette, changing it differs from terminal to terminal, You might be using a 256 colors `tmux` if so, make sure you `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that my shell scheme has an error (base16-shell) that can be worked around until the author fixes it https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell/issues/30

It now works as it should. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)